# running terraform apply only for new outputs

Tags: terraform

I want to add an output to use in `terraform_remote_state` data source
for example:

```
output "acm_certificate_arn" {
  value       = module.acm_certificate.arn
  description = "arn main certificate"
}
```

Plan includes:

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + acm_certificate_arn = [
      + "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-123:11111111111:certificate/e6f1edf300--f33fl-number",
    ]
```

I can't run apply/refresh for various reasons, remote infra changed, and the state isn't up to date.
Is there a way of running something like plan --target=output.acm_certificate_arn? or my only options are modifying the state file and add the output I needed?
(Tried to apply on empty plan with target resource that had no changes, no luck)

Answer (score 1):

Since your output value presumably depends indirectly on some resources declared inside your module, `-target` wouldn't be a viable answer here even if Terraform did support targeting output values: `-target` selects the given object *and everything it depends on*, so that would still select all of the resources you seem to want to avoid updating.

Instead, this might be good situation for a *refresh-only plan*, which is one of the non-default [planning modes](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/plan#planning-modes). That planning mode will tell Terraform to skip asking providers to compare configuration with state and propose changes, and instead just focus on updating the state with the latest state of your existing objects *and* re-evaluating the dependent constructs like output values.

```
terraform apply -refresh-only
```

This is just a variation of the normal plan and apply flow which disables the step of planning to make changes, so you'll still get the opportunity to review what Terraform is proposing to do before committing the result to the state. For a refresh-only plan though, applying the plan just means to create a new state snapshot based on the result of refreshing, and will not take any actions to modify the remote objects belonging to your resources.

Comment: Unfortunately running refresh isnt going to work for me.
As I said - the state / account wasn't maintained and I have a lot of changes, some are correct some are not - and I don't want to refresh my state to the working status of the infra.

Comment: If you can't even refresh then I think your only remaining option would be to run `terraform state pull` to copy the state into a local file, manually edit the data structure which records the output values to include only exactly what you want to record, and then push up the new snapshot with `terraform state push`. If you do that then you'll need to manually increment the `serial` attribute in the temporary file so that Terraform will see that you are intending to create a new snapshot.